# How to load content of a const variable from a file?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14, deserialization, constants

What is the method to save and retrieve contents (to/from a disk file) of an object who **has const** member variables?
Or more specifically, const members demand an initialization at the creation time of the object. So, the retrieval of the content has to happen before the initializers (before { } of the constructor). If we are not minding the encapsulation, we can retrieve and create the object with parameters. How to do everything by keeping the data-hiding?

---

Compiler: C++ 14 and maybe beyond.

---

Instantiation of the object, filling the content and storing for next context.

```
    { //CODE BLOCK 1 : making of content and saving to a diskfile
        Abcd abcd(65535,256,25);
        //some operations on abcd
        //save to disk
        QFile abcdFile("abcd.lion");
        abcdFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly);
        abcd.serialize(abcdFile);
        abcdFile.close();
    }
```

using same object after taking from file.

```
    { //CODE BLOCK 2 : loading from file and continue in another context
        QFile abcdFile("abcd.lion");
        abcdFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
        Abcd abcdNew(abcdFile);
        abcdFile.close();
        if(!abcdNew.isHealthy())
            printf("abcd from hdd is NOT Healthy :(\n");
        else
        {
            //doTheJob(abcdNew);
        }
    }
```

The class.

```
#include <QFile>
class Abcd
{
    const bool _healthy;//true if properly initialized
    //IMPORTANT: _healthy has to be the first member in the class.
    //this is to execute its initializer list first
protected:
    const long _rX;
    const long _rY;
          long _count;
public:
    Abcd(const long refX,
         const long refY,
         const long count) :
        _healthy(true),
        _rX(refX), _rY(refY),
        _count(count)
    {

    }
    Abcd(QFile &src) :
        _healthy(deserialize(src)),
        //Hack. Actually the initialization happened by this statement.
        //just keeping the below statements for the sake of syntactical correctness. :(
        _rX(_rX), _rY(_rY)
        //,_count(count)
    {

    }
    virtual
    ~Abcd()
    {

    }
    inline
    bool isHealthy()
    {
        return _healthy;
    }
    bool serialize(QFile &dest)
    {
        if(dest.write((char *)&_rY,sizeof(_rY))!=sizeof(_rY)) return false;
        if(dest.write((char *)&_rX,sizeof(_rX))!=sizeof(_rX)) return false;
        if(dest.write((char *)&_count,sizeof(_count))!=sizeof(_count)) return false;
        return true;
    }
private:
    bool deserialize(QFile &src)
    {
        if(src.read((char *)&_rY,sizeof(_rY))!=sizeof(_rY)) return false;
        if(src.read((char *)&_rX,sizeof(_rX))!=sizeof(_rX)) return false;
        if(src.read((char *)&_count,sizeof(_count))!=sizeof(_count)) return false;
        return true;
   }
};
```

Please suggest a better method. For this, I have introduced a ‘healthy’ status member as the first member in the declaration of the class. Also in deserialization, I am fooling the compiler by casting the const variable to char * pointer.

Comment: Thought about a conclusion. I got two solutions. 1. deserialize() as static function which uses RVO & exception error reporting. 2. a separate save/retrieve object for each kind of media(like disk file, cloud etc). I used 1st one for my purpose. A copy-constructor was created as RVO is not enabled in debug build in my specific compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to split up the logic of Abcd and serialization/deserialization into two classes.

Benefits:

- no field `_healthy` as object is always valid by design.
- class `Abcd` does only one job. Is free from any logic of storing (Single responsibility)

Few hints:

- RVO is mandatory since c++ 17
- `const` fields just make the object not copy/move assignable (unable to use with containers etc.). Simply properly use const correctness to ensure immutability.
- do not inherit implementation, only interfaces: Abcd is final, no virtual methods - better performance.
- follow the [Cpp Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines)

```
class Abcd final
{
public:
    Abcd(const long refX, const long refY, const long count)
        : _rX(refX)
        , _rY(refY)
        , _count(count)
    {
    }

    long GetRX() const
    {
        return _rX;
    }

    long GetRY() const
    {
        return _rY;
    }

    long GetCount() const
    {
        return _count;
    }

protected:
    long _rX;
    long _rY;
    long _count;
};
```

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <QFile>

template <typename T>
using Opt = boost::optional<T>; // or equivalent

// Choose better name for Serializer or even split it up
class AbcdSerializer final
{
public:
    AbcdSerializer(QFile& file)
        : _file(file)
    {
    }

    // You may also throw an exception instead of returning optional
    Opt<Abcd> TryDeserializeAbcd()
    {
        long rX;
        long rY;
        long count;

        if (ReadValue(rY) && ReadValue(rX) && ReadValue(count))
        {
            return Abcd(rX, rY, count);
        }

        return {};
    }

    bool SerializeAbcd(const Abcd& abcd)
    {
        return WriteValue(abcd.GetRY()) && WriteValue(abcd.GetRX()) && WriteValue(abcd.GetCount());
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    bool ReadValue(T& value)
    {
        constexpr auto ValueSize = sizeof(value);

        return _file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), ValueSize) != ValueSize;
    }

    template <typename T>
    bool WriteValue(const T& value)
    {
        constexpr auto ValueSize = sizeof(value);

        return _file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&value), ValueSize) != ValueSize;
    }

    QFile& _file;
};
```

Comment: Appreciating your thinking process and effort spent for the reply. Almost, fully rewritten! I did not want to move to different discussions related to storage. So just used QFile. For mapping to different data source/destination, the natural choice will be _streams_. Then we can point the storage to a disk file, memory or cloud storage. Also, I want to keep my object self contained, not interested to give get/set functions for everything. surely, it may not be a choice for everyone. Anyway, thanks a lot for writing. Also, I am not using _boost_. It is new to me.

Comment: Qt has `QVariant`, there is `std::optional` since c++17.

Comment: You may also use `friend` - then no getters are required.

Setters (in the meaning of plain object state manipulation) are simply breaking encapsulation - so I didn't mention them at all ;).

Comment: ha ha... I cannot imagine friending. anyway got your point friend.. thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion will be to use a `static` member function of the class to retrieve the contents of the file from disk and construct an object after the contents have been retrieved successfully.

Instead of:

```
 Abcd(QFile &src) :
```

Use

```
static Abcd deserialize(QFile& src);
```

and implement it as:

```
Abcd Abcd::deserialize(QFile& src)
{
   long rX;
   long rY;
   long count;

   if(src.read((char *)&rY, sizeof(rY)) != sizeof(rY)) throw false;
   if(src.read((char *)&rX, sizeof(rX)) != sizeof(rX)) throw false;
   if(src.read((char *)&count, sizeof(count)) != sizeof(count)) throw false;

   return Abcd(rX, rY, count):
}
```

**PS** It's strange that you save `_rY` first and then `_rX`. There is nothing wrong, it's just strange.

Comment: Appreciating the approach. but it will lead to the creation of two objects. right?

Comment: If a compiler supports return value optimization (RVO), then it won't. Not only that, one of the newer versions of the standard, not sure whether it is C++14 or C++17, requires RVO.

Comment: @veenusAV, unless performance is a proven issue, I won't worry about it.

Comment: OK. Thank you. It is a solution. Hope RVO will work in our all platforms. Then about _rY and _rX, I am writing a grid. So, preferred row and column. It shows your attention to detail. Nice

Comment: I took this solution. Then a finding: the DEBUG build configuration by default, is not supporting RVO. Release is working fine. so I wrote a copy constructor. _config_ Windows, Qt creator, MS Visual 2015 compiler. It might be because of not updating binaries of new MSVC.